# Asset Catalog Compiler Error Xcode 9

Tags: ios, compiler-errors, xcode9, asset-catalog, xcode9beta6

I'm trying to compile my application using Xcode Version 9.0 (9A235) and got error: "Exception Raised during asset import (2)". Reveal in log gives me only this (see picture) no details at all. If I compile the same project in Xcode ersion 8.3.3 (8E3004b) it's just fine. Any clues?
[image: Error]

Comment: Update. Trying to build using Command Line, got Error: The following build commands failed:
 CompileAssetCatalog /Users/Someuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mutualink_Edge-daukytrejhlkmycaxotehvlctqiu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/atCommand\ Enterprise.app Force-NG/Media/@CommandImages.xcassets
(1 failure)

Comment: Update: I have deleted all icons from @Command AppIcon and was able to compile and run application. All those icons are in .png format. As soon as I have put them back, it fails.

Answer (score 3):

Remove derived data and just clean and run your project.

Comment: I updated from Xcode 8 > 9.4 and this seemed to solve the issue for me. Thanks!

Comment: Great Andy! This can help too

Answer (score 2):

I have solved issue. My @Command AppIcon set had @ in that name, I suppose from Xcode 9 it has been restricted to use special characters in AppIcon set. I removed it, namet it just Command AppIcon and was abble to compile and run. Anyway, I did not find any notice about it in Apple documentation, so be aware.

Answer (score 0):

Issue with some of the images in my project. Deleted all images and renamed them to generic names (i.e all characters, no special characters/numbers) and that fixed the issue.